# What is the best practise to host MongoDb in AWS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I generally install mongo on an ec2 instance .
But i came across many other methods on hosting a mongodb server in aws.

I am looking to learn the most effective way to do this. Thanks in advance.

This is just an educational question.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to use the mongoatlas service, they have several plans but they carry out a full deployment of your database with automatic backups, metrics, access and permission management, availability, set replicas, autoscaling, etc...

Finally they also use amazon to host their databases and it is an official service of mongodb.

https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas

The downside to using a simple amazon instance is to implement all of that and without a good backup procedure you could lose all your data if your instance dies.